# Input type file is sending data as text

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

I have the following simple view file:-

```
<form action="{{route('testupdate')}}" method="POST">
    {{csrf_field() }}
    <input type="file" name="avatar" >
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

In Controller file i am suppose to receive a file type input, but i just get the image name as text:-

```
public function teststore(Request $request){
        dd($request->all());
        //returned array:2 [▼
        // "_token" => "jFPlhBHXP9jLXCJkrlDg62wR8eVaiBJgEnTD8wBZ"
        //"avatar" => "2.png"

       dd($request->has('avatar'));
       // returned true

       dd($request->hasFile('avatar');
       //returned null (Although the input type is "file")
  }
```

Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
<form action="{{route('testupdate')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to include tag  `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your input field. This tag is necessary whenever you are using file uploads